# ADF force format stored in parquet from copy activity

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory

I've created an ADF pipeline that converts a delimited file to parquet in our datalake.  I've added an additional column and set the value using the following expression `@convertfromutc(utcnow(),'GMT Standard Time','o')`.  The problem I am having is when I look at the parquet file it is coming back in the US format.

eg 11/25/2021 14:25:49

Even if I use `@if(pipeline().parameters.LoadDate,json(concat('[{"name": "LoadDate" , "value": "',formatDateTime(convertfromutc(utcnow(),'GMT Standard Time','o')),'"}]')),NULL)` to try to force the format on the extra column it still comes back in the parquet in the US format.

Any idea why this would be and how I can get this to output into parquet as a proper timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention the format pattern while using **convertFromUtc** function as shown below.

`@convertFromUtc(utcnow(),’GMT Standard Time’,’yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’)`

- Added date1 column in additional columns under source to get the required date format.

[image]

- Preview of source data in mappings. Here data is previewed as giving format in **convertFromUtc** function.

[image]

- Output parquet file:

[image]

- Data preview of the sink parquet file after copying data from the source.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This did help me identify I had a comma in the wrong place in my expression.  For any other users having a similar issue.  Even though the documentation for both convertfromutc and formatDateTime show that using 'o' will output ISO format, and it does in the output of the task, when ADF outputs the data it still does it in US format.  If you give it the full yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffK format it outputs correctly.